# Add TextView dynamically in a different Activity (RelativeLayout)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I was trying to add a new TextView every time I click on a button, in a new activity (already created), but I encountered multiple errors such as Null Pointer Exception and Illegal State Exception too.

This is the code I used in the `button` activity, and it's activated when I press that `button`.
In the code I'm recalling the layout `activity_position` which is the activity I would like to add the `TextView` to.

```
 RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_position);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setId(10);
        tv.setText(addr);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rl.addView(tv);
```

Running this code gets me only errors (on rl.addView(tv) line) and I can't figure it out why. 
This is the XML of the activity where I would like to add the TextViews dynamically.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".PositionActivity" >
```

```
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3758)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4377)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18044)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3753)
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     ... 11 more
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 12:21:47.348: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at com.example.placeholder.LocatingActivity.getCoords(LocatingActivity.java:101)
```

EDIT: added the LogCat

Can you help me out?

Thank you!

FULL CODE: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3uaHczyJIVQVXhMR1lyN3JnWjQ&usp=sharing

Comment: what kind of error are you getting..???

Comment: post your logcat report.

Comment: if you have the "TextView tv = new TextView(this);" line inside your button's onClickListener(), then you need to change it.. Inside the onClickListener() , "this" doesn't refer to the activity's context.. You have to use getApplicationContext()

Comment: I'm inside the listener, and i tried to change this with getApplicationContext() but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root exception in your logcat output is in `LocatingActivity`, line 101. In that activity there are no `OnClickListener`s, so let's see if I got it right: you're trying to modify contents of an `Activity` from another `Activity` (I assume first one is under second one in the stack)?

You can't do that, ever. You can only manipulate views/layouts of the activity that's currently active (i.e. shown), all other activities are paused and may have even been destroyed.

I suggest you read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html along with other basic documentation on the site.

Comment: Ok thank you. Then  should I create all my TextViews in the onCreate() method of the (second) activity I want to show the TextViews?

Comment: Of course, you don't have any other option. You can only create views in activity that is currently shown. If you want to create text views in your second activity - you should do it in onCreate() of you second activity.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are trying to cast `R.layout.activity_position` to `RelativeLayout`.  assign id to RelativeLayout then use R.id.relatv_layout to in code as:

in xml :

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relatv_layout"
     ....
    tools:context=".PositionActivity" >
```

In code use `R.layout.relatv_layout` to initialize `rl` :

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relatv_layout);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is still getting me the same error. I posted the logcat on the question thread.

Comment: @AndreaMontanari: please add full code of Activity to get more help

Answer (score 0):

Full answer:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout LL;
    private RelativeLayout RL;
    private Button btn;


    int click_counter = 0;


    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        RL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

        LL = new LinearLayout(this);
        LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        RL.addView(LL);

        // Listener
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tv.setText("Click: " + ++click_counter);
                LL.addView(tv);
            }
        });



    } // onCreate()





}
```

and layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if I do this, it doesn't even start my first activity!

Comment: I now, there was a mistake in my code:
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.**id_relative_layout**);

Comment: I corrected the code, but it still freezes on the first activity giving a NPE

Comment: I gave one of the variants of answers